# Space between list, space on left side of the ul. How to remove this?

Tags: html, css, list, margin, space

***I don't want spaces between my list and there is also a space on left side. And please tell me how to have simple scrolling effect with pure css. And please tell me a source from where i can learn about the compatibility issues between css properties (if there is any)***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 3em;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu_advanced_search:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #0066FF;
}
#menu_advanced_search {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #0066FF;
}
#menu_explore:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
#menu_explore {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
#menu_forum:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #009900;
}
#menu_forum {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #009900;
}
#menu_report_a_bug:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
#menu_report_a_bug {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
#menu_feedback:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #CC0099;
}
#menu_feedback {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #CC0099;
}
#menu_login_signup:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#menu_login_signup {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#main {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#advanced_search {
  background-color: #0066FF;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#explore {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#forum {
  background-color: #009900;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#report_a_bug {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#feedback {
  background-color: #CC0099;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#login_signup {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>CARZPEDIA</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="menu_advanced_search"><a href="#advanced_search">ADVANCED SEARCH</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_explore"><a href="#explore">EXPLORE</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_forum"><a href="#forum">FORUM</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_report_a_bug"><a href="#report_a_bug">REPORT A BUG</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_feedback"><a href="#feedback">FEEDBACK</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_login_signup"><a href="#login_signup">LOGIN/SIGNUP</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="advanced_search" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="explore" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="forum" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="report_a_bug" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="feedback" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="login_signup">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try `#nav ul{padding: 0;}`

Comment: That's this really great search engine called Google that you can use to find the answers to your questions. You will have to go to the effort of typing in some search queries and looking at some web pages, but it will be worth it!

Comment: I usually start by 'Googling' but since my question was too messed up even google begged me to not ask to him about that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this by doing the following:

```
#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0; /* add padding-left: 0; to remove the space on left side of the ul */
    font-size: 0; /* add font-size: 0; to remove the white space between inline-block elements */
}
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 3em;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0 1em;
    font-size: 16px; /* add font-size: 16px; to reset the font-size to li (i.e 1em = 16px) */
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 3em;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: 16px;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu_advanced_search:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #0066FF;
}
#menu_advanced_search {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #0066FF;
}
#menu_explore:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
#menu_explore {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
#menu_forum:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #009900;
}
#menu_forum {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #009900;
}
#menu_report_a_bug:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
#menu_report_a_bug {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
#menu_feedback:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #CC0099;
}
#menu_feedback {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #CC0099;
}
#menu_login_signup:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#menu_login_signup {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#main {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#advanced_search {
  background-color: #0066FF;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#explore {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#forum {
  background-color: #009900;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#report_a_bug {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#feedback {
  background-color: #CC0099;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#login_signup {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>CARZPEDIA</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="menu_advanced_search"><a href="#advanced_search">ADVANCED SEARCH</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_explore"><a href="#explore">EXPLORE</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_forum"><a href="#forum">FORUM</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_report_a_bug"><a href="#report_a_bug">REPORT A BUG</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_feedback"><a href="#feedback">FEEDBACK</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_login_signup"><a href="#login_signup">LOGIN/SIGNUP</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="advanced_search" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="explore" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="forum" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="report_a_bug" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="feedback" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="login_signup">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks! nice explanation and a working answer. If you don't mind i have one more problem i want my menu to change color when the link is viewed In my case am using id's so when when the browser is displaying particular part of the page i want my menu to change its background color. Example: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: no i mean after clicking the link like in http://www.wampserver.com/en/ when we click downloads download menu have an orange background

Comment: You need to use JavaScript or jQuery because you can't select the links and change the background color with css selectors - http://jsfiddle.net/onkagL73/embedded/result/ and You should try [Bootstrap ScrollSpy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) or [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on SO. Good Luck! :)

Comment: oops!! am really sorry i  didn't read your name I just you know.... Well I apologize for that :(

Comment: @VOXRAZR It's fine! :)

Answer (score 1):

add `float:left` for `#nav li` it will fix the issue

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 3em;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 1em;
  float:left;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu_advanced_search:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #0066FF;
}
#menu_advanced_search {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #0066FF;
}
#menu_explore:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
#menu_explore {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
#menu_forum:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #009900;
}
#menu_forum {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #009900;
}
#menu_report_a_bug:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
#menu_report_a_bug {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
#menu_feedback:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #CC0099;
}
#menu_feedback {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #CC0099;
}
#menu_login_signup:hover {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#menu_login_signup {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #000000;
}
#main {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#advanced_search {
  background-color: #0066FF;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#explore {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#forum {
  background-color: #009900;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#report_a_bug {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#feedback {
  background-color: #CC0099;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#login_signup {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>CARZPEDIA</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li id="menu_advanced_search"><a href="#advanced_search">ADVANCED SEARCH</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_explore"><a href="#explore">EXPLORE</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_forum"><a href="#forum">FORUM</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_report_a_bug"><a href="#report_a_bug">REPORT A BUG</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_feedback"><a href="#feedback">FEEDBACK</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu_login_signup"><a href="#login_signup">LOGIN/SIGNUP</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="advanced_search" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="explore" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="forum" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="report_a_bug" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="feedback" class="scrolleffect">
  </div>
  <div id="login_signup">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to use reset css http://www.cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/ which will remove all `padding` `margin`

Comment: or every browser will have its own default styles for elements

Comment: or try normalize.css to makes browsers render elements consistently - http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

add `display:inline-block` for `#nav li`.  It will fix the issue and avoid the pain points of floats.

Comment: Please look carefully its already in my code anyway thanks :)